# Why is heavy attack of Grave Digger weak in God of War: Ghost of Sparta?

Tags: god-of-war-ghost-of-sparta

A couple of weeks ago I beat God of War: Ghost of Sparta for PSP. I collected all one million orbs and unlocked everything in the Temple of Zeus, I finished all of the challenges, and then I started to enjoy playing with Grave Digger in the Combat Arena.

Now I'm trying to determine how powerful his attacks are. As the game does not have anything that can measure player attack power directly, I measure it by calculating how many combos/hits are needed to kill a specific creature.

Considering the following two combos:

`normal combo = square, square, square, square, square`

`heavy combo = hold triangle, triangle`

I calculated the number of hits, regardless if they are sequentially or not, needed to kill the Piraeus Lion, which I think it is a creature with the most resistance to attacks:

`13 hits` needed using circle only

`21 hits` needed using square only  (with combo)

`25 hits` needed using square only  (without combo)

`32 hits` needed using R only

And incredibly:

`50 hits` needed using triangle only (heavy combo or not)

I thought that triangle is supposed to be the strongest attack, so why does it require so many hits to kill it? It it something about the Grave Digger? Or something about the Lion? Or something about that attack?

Comment: Hey Patrick! I stripped your question down to focus on what you wanted to know and essential information. Extra information is ok, but users tend to ignore lengthy questions, and that might prevent someone who knows the answer from helping you. If you want to add any information back, you're more than welcome to, it's your question :)

Comment: I understand, Thank you. But you remove my spoiler joke :/

Comment: @SadlyNot I might have committed a bunch of mistakes on the original question, but imagine how ironic it is to me when I saw one of your edit reasons as "improved grammer". Anyway, just a joke...

Comment: I have no sense of humor, you should add the joke back if you like it!

Comment: @SadlyNot No need for that. I agree with your edition.